# Edit IEnumerable collection of items simultaneously in a View in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have a collection of items, name it type "A", that I want to view and edit some of its attributes in a View. I would like it to save simultaneously, however, this does not seem to work as it does not seem like it is passing anything back to the Post method.

**My Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult inline(IEnumerable<A> listA)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= listA.Count(); i++ )
    {
        A theObj = listA.ElementAt(i);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }  //Somehow this is returning to be Null
}
```

**My View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<A>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.EditorForModel("Multiple")
}
```

So far this prints out all the Id of the entries (with no formatting/line breaks, of course) for some reason.

And I am not sure how to create an editor template "Multiple", this is what I have so far:

```
@model Models.A
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Id)
```

I'm not sure where to put it / create it, so I just made it as another view in the same folder.

Any pointers how I can make this to work, so that I can edit multiple entries of the same object in the same view and pass it back to the controller and save it? I'm a newbie to MVC, so if this seems like a really simple question, I apologize in advance. Thanks!

Comment: Check this out http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Editor templates should reside in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder.

Comment: @JamieD77 Thanks for the pointer, would you have any idea how to start the Editor Template properly? Thanks again.

Comment: http://blog.learningtree.com/editing-collections-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most things in programming, there's multiple ways to achieve this. If you want to go the editor template route, though, it's pretty straight-forward.

As @JamieD77 pointed out, editor templates go into `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`. The most important part of that path is the `EditorTemplates` directory convention, though. Just as with any other view in MVC, you can override/fallback depending on where you place your view. For example, `Areas\Foo\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`, will work as well, but then it's only available to the `Foo` area. Or, you can override it for a particular controller by placing it in `Views\Foo\EditorTemplates`.

Then, the name of the view should correspond with the type it's intended to be used with. In your case, the view should be named `A.cshtml`. You can technically specify the view name manually by either passing it to `EditorFor` or using something like `UIHint`, but it's easier and more foolproof to just rely on convention here.

Inside this view, you should create the look and feel you want to have a for a single instance of `A`, with all editable properties represented. Then, in your main view, you simply call `Html.EditorFor` on the collection property, which in your case here, is the whole model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

Razor will realize it has a collection and render the editor template for each item in the collection. Importantly, because it has this context, it will also be able to generate the appropriate indexes on the field names.

If you did something like the following instead:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => item)
}
```

Your field names would *not* be indexed, and the modelbinder would not know what to do with the posted data. If you wanted to use a loop, you would have to use indexing inside the loop:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i])
}
```

That then gives Razor the proper context to generate appropriate field names. However, importantly, that approach requires utilizing a `List<T>` structure, rather than something like `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>`.