# Passing Multiple Form Objects to Ajax Controller Failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a ASP Core Razor form with multiple objects.  For simplicity's sake, let's say it's an employee object and the form allows you to edit multiple employees on the same page.

I am using a technique put the objects on the page like this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31709184/1359788

```
<form id="emp_frm" method="post">
...    

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i])
}
...
</form>
```

But I need to do an javascript(/jquery) ajax verification of some of the fields while the user is editing the form (but before it is submitted).

Normally, I would use a $("#emp_frm").serializeArray() to get the form names/values and pass them in the ajax data: field.  But with the multiple objects, this doesn't seem to work.  On my Ajax controller method, it looks like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetEmployees(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
```

but it always comes in as null no matter what I have in the form.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your `Ajax` call that you have defined at the moment ? If you have a complex model that you need to send to your `Controller`, I would suggest sending it as a `JSON` string and then de-serializing it on the `Controller` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `$("#emp_frm").serilalize()` rather than `$("#emp_frm").serializeArray()`:

```
 var s = $("#emp_frm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
                    url: "GetEmployees",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: s,           
                    success: function (response) {

                        //end of Ajax
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work either.  I took a different route with multiple forms on the page (instead of 1 form with multiple objects) that worked pretty easily.